# How to create a new object and alter another references

Tags: c#

How can I do this without losing the reference of X on Y ?

```
        public class Test
        {
            public void Main()
            {
                AbstractClass X = new Foo();

                Test2 test2 = new Test2(X);

                X = new Bar(); // I need to change Y as well.

                //Now, X is Bar, and Y is Foo. 
                if (X == test2.Y)
                    MessageBox.Show("They are equal! Success!!");
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Not equal :( ");
            }
        }

        public class Test2
        {
            public AbstractClass Y { get; set; }

            public Test2(AbstractClass y)
            {
                Y = y;
            }
        }

        public abstract class AbstractClass
        { }

        public class Foo : AbstractClass
        { }

        public class Bar : AbstractClass
        { }
```

Comment: Please explicitly state what you are trying to do: it is not clear at all.

Comment: basically, you **can't**

Comment: @Selman22 Yeah, but he wants to know how to do this, in another way, without losing the reference of X and Y.

Comment: @GuilhermeOliveira And the answer is: You can't. It's hard to find a proper workaround for a question as vague as this one.

Comment: @GolezTrol Vague? I can see two workarounds answered here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. If you need something like that you can wrap the `AbstractClass` in another and pass that as reference.

Here's how you go:

```
public class MyPropertyStore
{
    public AbstractClass MyProperty {get;set;}
}

public class Test2
{      
    private MyPropertyStore propertyStore;
    public AbstractClass Y { get { return propertyStore.MyProperty ;} }

    public Test2(MyPropertyStore propertyStore)
    {
        this.propertyStore= propertyStore;
    }
}

public void Main()
{
    AbstractClass X = new Foo();
    MyPropertyStore store = new MyPropertyStore 
    {
     MyProperty  = X,
    };
    Test2 test2 = new Test2(store);

    store.MyProperty = new Bar(); // Now test2.Y will be pointing to same reference

    //Now, X is Bar, and Y is Foo. 
    if (X == test2.Y)
        MessageBox.Show("They are equal! Success!!");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Not equal :( ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you try to achieve but I assume you want the fowllowing to happen:

```
public void Main()
{
    AbstractClass X = new Foo();

    Test2 test2 = new Test2(X);

    X = new Bar(); 

    // change test2.Y
    test2.Y = X;

    if (X == test2.Y)
        MessageBox.Show("They are equal! Success!!");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Not equal :( ");
}
```